# joomla add data to user

Tags: database, joomla

I would like to know if there is a way to add some data to users in joomla 1.6. For example I have data website that should gather data using a different database for each user. I would like to store the database informations (user, pass, db) for each of them to then load a user specific page (you know, google, facebook, etc way).

In Concrete5 you can add "attributes" to users, which could be a good way in joomla?

Comment: EDIT:
I found in the documentation a class JUser. Maybe using the methods JUser->setParam and getParam the job would do. Since this two methods exist in the api, shouldn't exist a way to do that through the back end?

Answer (score 1):

There is a table called

> jos_user_profiles

This has the fields:

> user_id, profile_key, profile_value, ordering

Seem's like this is the table your data should be stored in.
Don't know if there's a function for that in the backend.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for a back end solution, or if it's not possible at least an API way. I don't want to modify manually the database.

Comment: mhm you could write yourself one, and use this table :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found solution or not BUT...

You need to populate the following tables:

**Add user to:** jos_users

**Assign the user aro:** jos_core_acl_aro

**Create relation between aro and user group:** jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map

Comment: Thanks to both, but i was thinking about a more API way like $user->setData(associativeArray)